# change Keyboard layout for startup in Scientifc Linux 6

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I installed Scientific Linux 6 on my work machine and chose the wrong keymap during installation.

Changing it when once you're logged in is easy. But the problem is that for the login screen the keyboard layout is still the other one. How can I change it?

PS: keyboard-configuration doesn't seem to exist at my system...